# Search LDAP for a user with a specific IP address

Tags: ip, ldap, search, edirectory

I am doing passthrough authentication against a Novell eDirectory server.  Currently I perform the following request:

```
results = server.search_s(
    self.basedn,
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    '(objectClass=user)',
    attrlist=['uid', 'networkAddress'])
```

<sub>(This is in python, let me know if you want me to explain it.)</sub>

The problem with this method is that each query returns every single user on the server, which I then have to loop through to find the user I'm interested in.  I cache it, but what I'd really like to do is something like this:

```
results = server.search_s(
    self.basedn,
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    '(&(objectClass=user)(networkAddress=#9#\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\n\x1e))')
```

<sub>(That wacky `#9#` stuff is how the IP is stored - it's actually 192.168.10.30)</sub>

When I do a query for `networkAddress` I get an `'Invalid Syntax'` error (even if I do something like `networkAddress=blah`, without all the `\`'s).

Is there a way to do an LDAP query for a specific IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Network Address is using a syntax of Net Address which is a structured attribute.  I wrote about the various syntax types in these pair of articles:

http://www.novell.com/communities/node/6450/interesting-schema-syntaxes-edirectory-identity-manager-perspective-part-1
http://www.novell.com/communities/node/6457/interesting-schema-syntaxes-edirectory-identity-manager-perspective-part-2

The # signs separate fields in the LDAP view of the attribute.

I was looking at the schema reference for those articles in LogicSource for NDS, which was a for fee document.

The question is what is the comparison allowed on that attribute.

On a side point, if your queried for loginTime=* that would show those who are currently logged in, and would reduce the set of users to loop through.

Also, networkAddress is multivalued.

Comment: Great answer, but it seems changing the query to '(&(loginTime=*)(objectClass=user))' returns every user who has ever logged in.  Numbers:
all = 1101
after adding loginTime=* = 1046
users with uid and networkAddress = 55

Comment: Ah hah!  If I make the query '(&(networkAddress=*)(objectClass=user))' it gives me a much smaller subset of users.  Looks like that's what I want.

Comment: Right, sorry forgot, Login Time remains...  I guess if you could filter loginTime in the search with a less than filter, that would be good, but alas you cannot do that either.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the code you're actually running doesn't have an unescaped apostrophe inside the string?

Comment: Woops, sorted that now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a single quote in the wrong place in your search filter.  Should it rather be:

```
results = server.search_s(
    self.basedn,
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    '(&(objectClass=user)(networkAddress=#9#\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\n\x1e))'
)
```